# How to dynamically increase the row height using Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I have a table using ag-Grid. I would like to adjust the row height according to the text in the cell. In documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/index.php it was given for specific column. But in my case any column can have more text. So how to adjust the row height according to the largest text size in any of the column.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            angularCompileRows: true,
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFilter: true,
            groupHeaders: true,
            suppressCellSelection: true,
            columnDefs: cols,
            rowData: statusPageObj.rows,
            onGridReady: opmGridReady,
            angularCompileRows: true,
            headerHeight: 45,
            /*rowHeight: 50,*/
            getRowHeight: function(params) {
               return 50;
            }

        };
```

Comment: any comments on this?

Comment: You can use `params.data` inside of the `getRowHeight` function. This is the data that you provide to the grid initially, then you would just need to iterate through all your rows and then all your cells to find which one has the largest text length

Comment: @JarodMoser that will cause performance issue right? because i have a very big json

Comment: probably, but if you really want to change the row height depending on whichever cell has the largest content, then I don't really see any other way besides iterating through every cell that you have. Your other option is to guess at what the largest height is that you need and set it from the beginning

Comment: but I have no idea how much of a performance impact it will have. So you might as well try it out and see how much longer the load time is.

Comment: @JarodMoser thanks mate.. I will try it out

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the height of the row based on the text-length.

```
gridOptions.getRowHeight = function() {
     return 18 * (Math.floor(params.data.myDataField.length / 45) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**step:1** html code

```
<button onclick="setrowHeight(50)">50px</button>
```

**step:2** js code

```
var rowHeight = 25;

function setrowHeight(height) {
    rowHeight = height;
    gridOptions.api.resetRowHeights();
}
```

*watch this*: https://embed.plnkr.co/FEK7wtQfVwUXeYjOh6PK/

Comment: this is not dynamic

Comment: @solanki Can you please recheck your example its not loading throwing error that https://run.plnkr.co/k7lygeiP3eUD3Tpt/ag-grid-community 404 (Not Found).